Error 403 - Forbidden after setting up PE on same VNET
I have like 20 tabs open of random SO and Azure docs. I created an App Service - it worked great w/ public access. We are moving it to use PE. The PE was setup using a VNET . I see the private IP now in the App Service (yay).
I saw that it created a private dns zone and had the a record and cname for routing inside the VNET through the private link. This matches expectations.
I'm now on a VM on that same VNET - when I hit the URL of the app service I am greeted w/ the 403 Forbidden (same as outside the VNET as expected). This is the main doc I'm focusing on - it says "You must set up a private DNS server or an Azure DNS private zone." - the latter performed.
I even tried playing w/ the host entry like it mentioned but no luck.
Here is the current nslookup result
C:\Windows\system32>nslookup my-azure-app.azurewebsites.net
Server:  azure-dc.company.local
Address:  10.99.1.132

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    waws-prod-bn1-179-e41c.eastus2.cloudapp.azure.com
Address:  20.119.128.8
Aliases:  my-azure-app.azurewebsites.net
          my-azure-app.privatelink.azurewebsites.net
          waws-prod-bn1-179.sip.azurewebsites.windows.net

Any advice?

Update
I created a new 2nd VM 10.99.25.6 - this one I have not allowed network team to change any DNS, I just put straight on the VNET and it's using Azure DNS.
This one the nslookup seems better, however when accessing the site it just spins for a bit then times out.
C:\Users\admin>nslookup my-azure-app.azurewebsites.net
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  168.63.129.16

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    my-azure-app.privatelink.azurewebsites.net
Addresses:  168.63.129.16
          10.99.25.5
Aliases:  my-azure-app.azurewebsites.net


Kindly share the result of nslookup <your_web_app_name>.azurewebsites.net from a VM connected to the same VNet

Hi @Poat , Have you created a virtual link in the private DNS zone? 10.99.1.132 Is this your PE IP?

@VenkatV a vnet link was created automatically during setup.  10.99.1.132 is one of our company's DC's, on a diff vnet.  my VM is 10.99.25.4 and the PE IP is 10.99.25.5

Have you created peering for both VNETs and removed the host entry if they are all on the same network with peering enabled?

@VenkatV you've been a great help - can you help me w/ this latest snag on a new VM - now it's timing out.


I'm now on a VM on that same VNET - when I hit the URL of the app service I am greeted w/ the 403 Forbidden (same as outside the VNET as expected).
Error 403 - Forbidden after setting up PE on same VNET

The error you encountered is due to a DNS forwarder not being created correctly in the DNS server to forward the traffic to 168.63.129.16.
To resolve the issue, you should create a Forward Lookup Zone for azurewebsites.net and point it to 168.63.129.16. This setup will only work if you have a custom DNS server with the IP address 10.99.1.132 in Azure.
For on-premises workloads to resolve an FQDN of a private endpoint to the private IP address, you must use a DNS forwarder in Azure. This forwarder will be responsible for resolving all DNS queries via a server-level forwarder to the Azure-provided DNS at 168.63.129.16.
In my case, I used the Azure-provided DNS server, which resolved the web app from the VM correctly and made it accessible.

References: Azure Private DNS Zone Resolution from On-prem by GitaraniSharma-MSFT
Azure Private Endpoint private DNS zone values for Web

OK let me work w/ our network team on this.  I have updated the answer for a new VM which shouldn't need forwarders as it's on Azure DNS.  If this works I'll accept since ultimately I'll be using company DNS.

Please check if any NSG rules or firewall rules are blocking traffic. Troubleshoot the issue from the VM by following the instructions in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/troubleshoot-private-endpoint-connectivity

yes!  Was NSG.  Now I am setting up forwarder

what is your DNS servers in your ipconfig?  on premise?  your picture here is using azure dns which works fine for me

I used Azure DNS, if you are using private DNS, you must use a DNS forwarder in Azure
